# Problem when rename file in Azure Databricks from a data lake

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I am trying to rename a file with Python in Azure Databricks through the "import os" library using the "rename ()" function, it is something very simple really, but when doing it in Databricks I can't get to the path where my file is. in the Data Lake, but doing a command "% fs ls path_file" yes I see it, I can even read it and process it with pyspark without problems.

I leave an example of my code:

```
import os
old_name = r"/mnt/datalake/path/part-00000-tid-1761178-3f1b0942-223-1-c000.csv"
new_name = r"/mnt/datalake/path/example.csv"

os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

The above returns an error that does not find the path or file, but an "ls" command does that same path with out problem.

On the other hand, I have tried to rename the file with pySpark, but it uses a hadoop library (org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration) that I do not have installed and I cannot install it in the production environment ...

What would I be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you're using `os.rename`, you need to refer files as `/dbfs/mnt/...` because you're using [local API to access DBFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#access-files-on-dbfs).

But really, it could be better to use [dbutils.fs.mv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--mv-command-dbutilsfsmv) to do file renaming:

```py
old_name = r"/mnt/datalake/path/part-00000-tid-1761178-3f1b0942-223-1-c000.csv"
new_name = r"/mnt/datalake/path/example.csv"

dbutils.fs.mv(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the delay in my response, I had not sent it last time, it helped me a lot.
regards!

Answer (score 1):

Use this.
Replace the path to your path

```
old_name = r"dbfs:/FileStore/tables/PM/TC/ROBERTA"
new_name = r"dbfs:/FileStore/tables/PM/TC/BERT"

dbutils.fs.mv(old_name, new_name, True)
```