# Compress CSV to ZIP in dbfs (databricks file storage)

Tags: python, zip, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to compress a csv, located in an azure datalake, to zip. The operation is done with python code in databricks, where I created a mount point to relate directly dbfs with the datalake.

This is my code:

```
import os
import zipfile 

csv_path= '/dbfs/mnt/<path>.csv'
zip_path= '/dbfs/mnt/<path>.zip' 

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w') as zip:
    zip.write(csv_path)  # zipping the file
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

Is there any way of doing it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do like you did.  The main reason is that [local DBFS API has limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations) - it doesn't support random writes that is required when you're creating a zip file.

The workaround would be following - output zip file to the local disk of the driver node, and then use `dbutils.fs.mv` to move file to DBFS, something like this:

```py
import os
import zipfile 

csv_path= '/dbfs/mnt/<path>.csv'
zip_path= '/dbfs/mnt/<path>.zip' 
local_path = '/tmp/my_file.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(local_path, 'w') as zip:
    zip.write(csv_path)  # zipping the file
dbutils.fs.mv(f"file:{local_path}", zip_path)
```

Comment: This is woking for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got same error below while reproducing this.

[image]

But I am able to compress csv file into zip by **converting to dataframe and then to zip** like below.

```
df=spark.read.csv("dbfs:/mnt/ok/csv1.csv")
df.coalesce(1).write.option("compression","gzip").csv("/dbfs/mnt/ok/myzip2.zip")
```

[image]

Please don't confuse with the path of csv above, here by mistake I have used another csv from ADLS.

You can see the zip file in dbfs below.

[image]

But coalesce gives the file name in the zip as part names. To rename it use `dbuits.fs.mv(old_path,new_path)`

- First get the csv file path using `ls`

  [image]
- Then use this path to rename to a new path like below.

```
old_name = r"/dbfs/mnt/ok/myzip2.zip/part-00000-tid-1285084120372550072-c8b0b7bd-b3b4-4432-8575-4e33e5328ec9-6-1-c000.csv.gz"
new_name=r"/dbfs/mnt/ok/myzip2.zip/mycsv.csv.gz"
dbutils.fs.mv(old_name, new_name)
```

The above code is referred from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826338/problem-when-rename-file-in-azure-databricks-from-a-data-lake) by **Alex Ott**.

After renaming:

[image]

Comment: it's about Zip file, not Gzip file

Comment: Yes, I need to output in Zip format. It is possible to get zip instead of gzip directly from df? @AlexOtt

Comment: Not directly via Spark...